# Python executable file doesn't display plots

Tags: python, runtime-error

I made a Python script that has a GUI and plots sets of data. But when I converted it to an executable file using PyInstaller, the GUI was working well but there were no plots.
On the console there was an error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
  File "adc_project.py", line 451, in plot_data
  File "matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 540, in figure
  File "matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 3358, in new_figure_manager
  File "matplotlib\backends\_backend_tk.py", line 897, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 4061, in __init__
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 4006, in __init__
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "C:\Users\phbar\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI31202\mpl-data\images\matplotlib_128.ppm": no such file or directory

Matplotlib version = 2.2.5
PyInstaller version = 4.0
Python version = 3.8.3
```

This is the full Python code; it creates a GUI, user is required to open a text file, computes and then plots the data from the text file.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import tkinter.scrolledtext as st
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import os
import sys
from tkinter import messagebox

ideal_list = []
adc_list = []
adc_list_int = []
global num_codes


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("ADC Linearity Analyzer")
window.geometry("562x172")
window.resizable(width=True, height = True)
##window.resizable(width=True, height = True)

frame1 = tk.LabelFrame(window, padx = 5, pady = 5)
frame1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 5, sticky = tk.W)

label_res = tk.Label(frame1, text = "ADC Resolution: ")
label_res.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = tk.S+tk.W)

entry_res = tk.Entry(frame1, width = 7)
entry_res.config(justify = tk.CENTER)
entry_res.grid(row = 2, column = 0, padx = 100, sticky = tk.W)

label_hits = tk.Label(frame1, text = "Hits per Code: ")
label_hits.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = tk.S+tk.W)

entry_hits = tk.Entry(frame1, width = 7)
entry_hits.config(justify = tk.CENTER)
entry_hits.grid(row = 3, column = 0, padx = 100, sticky = tk.W)

label_beyond = tk.Label(frame1, text = "LSB Beyond: ")
label_beyond.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = tk.S+tk.W)

entry_beyond = tk.Entry(frame1, width = 7)
entry_beyond.config(justify = tk.CENTER)
entry_beyond.grid(row = 4, column = 0, padx = 100, sticky = tk.W)

label_transpoint = tk.Label(frame1, text = "Transition Point: ")
label_transpoint.grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky = tk.W)

entry_transpoint = tk.Entry(frame1, width = 7)
entry_transpoint.config(justify = tk.CENTER)
entry_transpoint.grid(row = 5, column = 0, padx = 100, sticky = tk.W)

label_title = tk.Label(frame1, text = "Welcome to ADC Linearity Analyzer!")
label_title.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.W)

label_open = tk.Label(frame1, text = "Open datalog: ")
label_open.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = tk.W)

entry_file = tk.Entry(frame1, width = 54)
entry_file.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 100, columnspan = 2)
entry_file.config(justify = tk.LEFT)

var1 = tk.IntVar()
chck_window = tk.Checkbutton(frame1, text = "Window", variable = var1, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0)
chck_window.grid(row = 5, column = 1, padx = 10, sticky = tk.S+tk.W)

frame2 = tk.LabelFrame(window, padx = 5, pady = 5)

def open_file():
    entry_file.delete(0, 'end')
    global filename
    filename = askopenfilename()
    entry_file.insert(0, filename)

def restart_prog():
    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)
    
def plot_data():
    if entry_file.get() == "":
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Select a text file.")
    elif entry_res.get() == "":
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Enter ADC Resolution.")
    elif entry_hits.get() == "":
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Enter Hits per Code.")
    elif entry_beyond.get() == "":
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Enter LSB Beyond.")
    elif entry_transpoint.get() == "":
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Enter Transition Point.")
    else:
        btn_plot.configure(state = tk.DISABLED)
        btn_browse.configure(state = tk.DISABLED)
        window.geometry("562x645")
    ## creates a list from 0 to num_codes
    ## for best fit ramp
        res = int(entry_res.get())
        num_codes = 2**res
        num_hits = int(entry_hits.get())
        lsb_beyond = int(entry_beyond.get())
        transpoint = entry_transpoint.get()
    
        if transpoint == '1':
            hits_transpoint = num_hits
        elif transpoint == '0.5':
            if num_hits % 2 == 1:
                hits_transpoint = num_hits//2 + 1
            else:
                hits_transpoint = num_hits//2
    
        for h in range(0, num_codes):
            if h == 0:
                for e in range((num_hits*lsb_beyond) + int(hits_transpoint)):
                    ideal_list.append(h)
            if h == num_codes - 1:
                for n in range((num_hits*(lsb_beyond))+int(hits_transpoint)):
                    ideal_list.append(h)
            if h != 0 and h != num_codes:
                for i in range(num_hits):
                    ideal_list.append(h)
                
        with open(filename, 'r+') as read_obj:
            with open('adc_data.txt', 'w') as write_obj:
                for line in read_obj:
                    if (line[2:8] == 'ADC_DB' and line[10:13] != 'DNL'
                    and line[10:13] != 'Off' and line[10:13] != 'Gai'
                    and line[10:13] != 'wor' and line[10:13] != 'min'
                    and line[10:13] != 'INL' and line[10:13] != 'Mis'
                    and line[10:13] != 'Abs' and line[10:13] != 'Spa'
                    and line[10:13] != 'VB_' and line[8:11] != ' - '
                    and line[10:13] != 'Avg'):
                        f = write_obj.write(line[10:-1])

        with open('adc_data.txt', 'r+') as new_file:
            for line in new_file:
                adc_list.append(line[0:-1].rstrip('\n').replace(':', ','))
                adc_list_int = list(map(int, adc_list[0].split(',')))

##---------Missing Codes---------------------------------
        miss_codes_list = []
    ##Counts the number of iteration each code have
        sum_hits = 0
        count_hits = []
        ideal_count_hits = []
        for code in range(num_codes):
            u = Counter(adc_list_int)
            hits_count.insert(tk.INSERT, 'Code {} = {}\n'.format(code, u[code]))
            count_hits.append(u[code])
            if u[code] == 0:
                miss_codes_list.append(code)
                entry_misscode.insert(0, len(miss_codes_list))
                misscodes_list.insert(tk.INSERT, 'Code {}\n'.format(code))
            
            uu = Counter(ideal_list)
            ideal_count_hits.append(uu[code])
        
        if not miss_codes_list:
            entry_misscode.insert(0, "None")
            misscodes_list.insert(tk.INSERT, "No Missing\nCodes")

        sum_count_hits = 0
        sum_ideal_hits = 0
        sum_count_hits_list = []
        sum_ideal_hits_list = []
        for ele_count_hits in range(0, num_codes):
            sum_count_hits = sum_count_hits + count_hits[ele_count_hits]
            sum_count_hits_list.append(sum_count_hits)

        for ele_ideal_hits in range(0, num_codes):
            sum_ideal_hits = sum_ideal_hits + ideal_count_hits[ele_ideal_hits]
            sum_ideal_hits_list.append(sum_ideal_hits)
        
##---------DNL & INL--------------------------------
    ##get average hits per code
        for ele in range(1, (len(count_hits)-1)):
            sum_hits = sum_hits + count_hits[ele]
        
        ave_hits = sum_hits/(num_codes - 2)
        entry_avehits.insert(0, round(ave_hits, 5))

        dnl_code = []
        inl_code = []
        max_dnl_codes = []
        min_dnl_codes = []
        max_inl_codes = []
        inl_val = 0
        worst_INL = 0 
        worst_INLcode = 0

    
        for p in count_hits:
            dnl_per_code = (p / ave_hits) - 1
            dnl_code.append(dnl_per_code)

        dnl_code[0] = 0
        dnl_code[-1] = 0

        for d in range(len(dnl_code)):
            dnl_max = max(dnl_code)
            dnl_min = min(dnl_code)
            dnl_val = dnl_code[d]
            inl_val = inl_val + dnl_val
            inl_code.append(inl_val)
            dnl_list.insert(tk.INSERT, 'Code {} = {}\n'.format(d, round(dnl_val, 6)))
            inl_list.insert(tk.INSERT, 'Code {} = {}\n'.format(d, round(inl_val, 6)))
            if dnl_val == dnl_max:
                max_dnl_codes.append(d)
                dnlmax_list.insert(tk.INSERT, 'Code {}\n'.format(d))
            if dnl_val == dnl_min:
                min_dnl_codes.append(d)
                dnlmin_list.insert(tk.INSERT, 'Code {}\n'.format(d))

        for e in range(len(inl_code)):
            if abs(inl_code[e]) > abs(worst_INL):
                worst_INL = inl_code[e]
                worst_INLcode = e
    
        entry_dnl.insert(0, round(max(dnl_code), 6))
        entry_dnlmin.insert(0, round(min(dnl_code), 6))
        entry_inl.insert(0, 'Code {} = {}'.format(worst_INLcode, round(worst_INL, 6)))
    
##-----------------Absolute Error------------------------------
        actualNumofHits = 0
        idealNumofHits = 0
        absErr_list = []
        worstabsErr = 0
    
        for abscode in range(0, num_codes):
            if abscode == 0:
                absErr = 0.0
            elif (abscode > 0 and abscode < num_codes - 1):
                idealNumofHits = idealNumofHits + ideal_count_hits[abscode - 1]
                actualNumofHits = actualNumofHits + count_hits[abscode - 1]
            elif abscode == num_codes - 1:
                idealNumofHits = idealNumofHits + ideal_count_hits[abscode - 1] + num_hits
                actualNumofHits = actualNumofHits + count_hits[abscode - 1]

            absErr = (actualNumofHits - idealNumofHits) / num_hits
            absErr_list.append(absErr)
            abserr_list.insert(tk.INSERT, 'Code {} = {}\n'.format(abscode, absErr_list[abscode]))
            if abs(absErr) > abs(worstabsErr):
                worstabsErr = absErr
                       
        for maxabserrcode in range(len(absErr_list)):
            if (absErr_list[maxabserrcode] == worstabsErr):
                maxabserr_list.insert(tk.INSERT, 'Code {}\n'.format(maxabserrcode))

        entry_abserr.insert(0, worstabsErr)

##--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    ## Offset error
        idealhits_code0 = num_hits * (lsb_beyond + float(transpoint))
        offsetErr = (u[0] - idealhits_code0) / num_hits
        entry_offseterr.insert(0, round(offsetErr, 5))

    ## Gain error
        idealhits_lastcode = num_hits * ((lsb_beyond+1) + float(transpoint))
        last_code = (u[num_codes-1] - idealhits_lastcode) / num_hits
        gainerror = last_code + offsetErr
        entry_gainerr.insert(0, round(gainerror, 5))

    
        frame2.grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 75, sticky = tk.N + tk.W)
        lbl_hits.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.N + tk.W)
        hits_count.grid(row = 1, column = 0, rowspan = 2, columnspan = 2, sticky = tk.W)
        hits_count.configure(state = 'disable')

        lbl_dnl_list.grid(row = 0, column = 3, sticky = tk.N + tk.W)
        dnl_list.grid(row = 1, column = 3, rowspan = 2, columnspan = 2, sticky = tk.W)
        dnl_list.configure(state = 'disable')

        lbl_dnlmax_list.grid(row = 0, column = 5, sticky = tk.N + tk.W)
        dnlmax_list.grid(row = 1, column = 5, columnspan = 1, sticky = tk.N+tk.W)
        dnlmax_list.configure(state = 'disable')

        lbl_dnlmin_list.grid(row = 2, column = 5, sticky = tk.N + tk.W)
        dnlmin_list.grid(row = 2, column = 5, pady = 20, columnspan = 1, sticky = tk.N+tk.W)
        dnlmin_list.configure(state = 'disable')

        lbl_inl_list.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = tk.N + tk.W)
        inl_list.grid(row = 4, column = 0, rowspan = 2, columnspan = 2, sticky = tk.W)
        inl_list.configure(state = 'disable')

        lbl_abserr_list.grid(row = 3, column = 3, sticky = tk.N + tk.W)
        abserr_list.grid(row = 4, column = 3, rowspan = 2, columnspan = 2, sticky = tk.W)
        abserr_list.configure(state = 'disable')

        lbl_maxabserr_list.grid(row = 3, column = 5, sticky = tk.N + tk.W)
        maxabserr_list.grid(row = 4, column = 5, columnspan = 1, sticky = tk.N+tk.W)
        maxabserr_list.configure(state = 'disable')

        lbl_misscodes_list.grid(row = 5, column = 5, sticky = tk.N + tk.W)
        misscodes_list.grid(row = 5, column = 5, pady = 20, columnspan = 1, sticky = tk.N+tk.W)
        misscodes_list.configure(state = 'disable')

        label_avehits.grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx = 10, sticky = tk.N + tk.W)
        entry_avehits.grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx = 100, sticky = tk.N+tk.W)
        entry_avehits.configure(state = 'readonly')
        label_offseterr.grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 26, sticky = tk.N +tk.W)
        entry_offseterr.grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx = 100, pady = 25, sticky = tk.N +tk.W)
        entry_offseterr.configure(state = 'readonly')
        label_gainerr.grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx = 10, pady = 51, sticky = tk.N +tk.W)
        entry_gainerr.grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx = 100, pady = 50, sticky = tk.N +tk.W)
        entry_gainerr.configure(state = 'readonly')
        label_dnl.grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx = 190, sticky = tk.N+tk.W)
        entry_dnl.grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx = 290, sticky = tk.N+tk.W)
        entry_dnl.configure(state = 'readonly')
        label_dnlmin.grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx = 190, pady = 26, sticky = tk.N+tk.W)
        entry_dnlmin.grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx = 290, pady = 25, sticky = tk.N+tk.W)
        entry_dnlmin.configure(state = 'readonly')
        label_inl.grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx = 190, pady = 51, sticky = tk.N+tk.W)
        entry_inl.grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx = 290, pady = 50, sticky = tk.N+tk.W)
        entry_inl.configure(state = 'readonly')
        label_abserr.grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx = 380, sticky = tk.N+tk.W)
        entry_abserr.grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx = 470, sticky = tk.N+tk.W)
        entry_abserr.configure(state = 'readonly')
        label_misscode.grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx = 380, pady = 26, sticky = tk.N+tk.W)
        entry_misscode.grid(row = 6, column = 0, padx = 470, pady = 25, sticky = tk.N+tk.W)
        entry_misscode.configure(state = 'readonly')

##------------------------------------------------------------------------
        plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
        if (var1.get() == 0):
            fig1 = plt.figure(figsize = (20, 10))
        
            sub1 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
            sub1.plot(ideal_list, marker=".", lw = 0.3, label = "Ideal")
            sub1.plot(adc_list_int, lw = 1, marker = '.', label = "Actual")
            plt.title("ADC Plot")
            plt.legend()
            plt.grid(True)
   
            sub2 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
            sub2.hist(ideal_list, bins = num_codes, rwidth = 0.6, histtype = 'bar', label = "Ideal")
            sub2.hist(adc_list_int, bins = num_codes, rwidth = 0.3, histtype = 'bar', label = "Actual")
            plt.title("ADC Histogram")
            plt.legend()
            plt.grid(True)

  
            sub3 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
            sub3.plot(range(0, num_codes), dnl_code, lw = 0.6, linestyle = '-', label = "DNL")
            plt.yticks(fontsize = 8)
            plt.xticks(fontsize = 8)
            plt.title("DNL", y = -0.01)
            plt.grid(True)

            sub4 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
            sub4.plot(range(0, num_codes), inl_code, lw = 0.6, linestyle = '-', label = "INL")
            plt.xticks(fontsize = 8)
            plt.yticks(fontsize = 8)
            plt.title("INL",y = -0.01)
            plt.grid(True)

        else:
            fig1 = plt.figure(figsize = (20, 10))
        
            sub1 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
            sub1.plot(ideal_list, marker=".", lw = 0.3, label = "Ideal")
            sub1.plot(adc_list_int, lw = 1, marker = '.', label = "Actual")
            plt.title("ADC Plot")
            plt.legend()
            plt.grid(True)
   
            sub2 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
            sub2.hist(ideal_list, bins = num_codes, rwidth = 0.6, histtype = 'bar', label = "Ideal")
            sub2.hist(adc_list_int, bins = num_codes, rwidth = 0.3, histtype = 'bar', label = "Actual")
            plt.title("ADC Histogram")
            plt.legend()
            plt.grid(True)

  
            sub3 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
            sub3.plot(range(0, num_codes), dnl_code, lw = 0.6, linestyle = '-', label = "DNL")
            plt.yticks(fontsize = 8)
            plt.xticks(fontsize = 8)
            plt.title("DNL", y = -0.01)
            plt.grid(True)

            sub4 = plt.subplot(2, 2, 4)
            sub4.plot(range(0, num_codes), inl_code, lw = 0.6, linestyle = '-', label = "INL")
            plt.xticks(fontsize = 8)
            plt.yticks(fontsize = 8)
            plt.title("INL",y = -0.01)
            plt.grid(True)
        
            fig2 = plt.figure()
            plt.plot(ideal_list, marker=".", lw = 0.3, label = "Ideal")
            plt.plot(adc_list_int, lw = 1, marker = '.', label = "Actual")
            plt.ylabel("Codes")
            plt.xlabel("Hits")
            plt.title("ADC Plot")
            plt.legend()
            plt.grid(True)

            fig3 = plt.figure()
            plt.hist(ideal_list, bins = num_codes, rwidth = 0.5, histtype = 'bar', label = "Ideal")
            plt.hist(adc_list_int, bins = num_codes, rwidth = 0.3, histtype = 'bar', label = "Actual")
            plt.ylabel("Hits")
            plt.xlabel("Codes")
            plt.title("ADC Histogram")
            plt.legend()
            plt.grid(True)

            fig4 = plt.figure()
            plt.plot(range(0, num_codes), dnl_code, lw = 0.6, linestyle = '-', label = "DNL")
            plt.ylabel("DNL")
            plt.xlabel("Codes")
            plt.yticks(fontsize = 8)
            plt.xticks(fontsize = 8)
            plt.title("Differential Nonlinearity")
            plt.grid(True)

            fig5 = plt.figure()
            plt.plot(range(0, num_codes), inl_code, lw = 0.6, linestyle = '-', label = "INL")
            plt.ylabel("INL")
            plt.xlabel("Codes")
            plt.xticks(fontsize = 8)
            plt.yticks(fontsize = 8)
            plt.title("Integral Nonlinearity")
            plt.grid(True)

        fig6 = plt.figure()
        plt.plot(sum_ideal_hits_list, range(0, num_codes), label = "Ideal")
        plt.plot(sum_count_hits_list, range(0, num_codes), label = "INL")

        plt.grid(True)


        plt.show()
        

##------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
    
lbl_hits = tk.Label(frame2, text = "Hits per Code ")
hits_count = st.ScrolledText(frame2, width = 22, height = 10, font = ("Courier", 10))

lbl_dnl_list = tk.Label(frame2, text = "DNL per Code")
dnl_list = st.ScrolledText(frame2, width = 22, height = 10, font = ("Courier", 10))

lbl_dnlmax_list = tk.Label(frame2, text = "Codes with Max. DNL")
dnlmax_list = st.ScrolledText(frame2, width = 14, height = 3, font = ("Courier", 10))

lbl_dnlmin_list = tk.Label(frame2, text = "Codes with Min. DNL")
dnlmin_list = st.ScrolledText(frame2, width = 14, height = 3, font = ("Courier", 10))

lbl_inl_list = tk.Label(frame2, text = "INL per Code")
inl_list = st.ScrolledText(frame2, width = 22, height = 10, font = ("Courier", 10))

lbl_abserr_list = tk.Label(frame2, text = "Absolute Error per Code")
abserr_list = st.ScrolledText(frame2, width = 22, height = 10, font = ("Courier", 10))

lbl_maxabserr_list = tk.Label(frame2, text = "Worst Abs. Error Codes")
maxabserr_list = st.ScrolledText(frame2, width = 14, height = 3, font = ("Courier", 10))

lbl_misscodes_list = tk.Label(frame2, text = "Missing Codes")
misscodes_list = st.ScrolledText(frame2, width = 14, height = 3, font = ("Courier", 10))

label_avehits = tk.Label(window, text = "Average Hits: ")
entry_avehits = tk.Entry(window, width = 13, bg = "white")
entry_avehits.config(justify = tk.CENTER)

label_offseterr = tk.Label(window, text = "Offset Error: ")
entry_offseterr = tk.Entry(window, width = 13, bg = "white")
entry_offseterr.config(justify = tk.CENTER)

label_dnl = tk.Label(window, text = "Maximum DNL: ")
entry_dnl = tk.Entry(window, width = 13, bg = "white")
entry_dnl.config(justify = tk.CENTER)

label_dnlmin = tk.Label(window, text = "Minimum DNL: ")
entry_dnlmin = tk.Entry(window, width = 13, bg = "white")
entry_dnlmin.config(justify = tk.CENTER)

label_inl = tk.Label(window, text = "Worst INL: ")
entry_inl = tk.Entry(window, width = 28, bg = "white")
entry_inl.config(justify = tk.CENTER)

label_abserr = tk.Label(window, text = "Absolute Error: ")
entry_abserr = tk.Entry(window, width = 13, bg = "white")
entry_abserr.config(justify = tk.CENTER)

label_gainerr = tk.Label(window, text = "Gain Error: ")
entry_gainerr = tk.Entry(window, width = 13, bg = "white")
entry_gainerr.config(justify = tk.CENTER)

label_misscode = tk.Label(window, text = "Missing Codes: ")
entry_misscode = tk.Entry(window, width = 13, bg = "white")
entry_misscode.config(justify = tk.CENTER)

btn_browse = tk.Button(frame1, text = "Browse", width = 12, command = open_file)
btn_browse.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 1, sticky = tk.E)

btn_clear = tk.Button(frame1, text = "Restart", width = 12, command = restart_prog)
btn_clear.grid(row = 4, column = 1, padx = 1, sticky = tk.E)

btn_plot = tk.Button(frame1, text = "Run", width = 12, command = plot_data)
btn_plot.grid(row = 5, column = 1, padx = 1, sticky = tk.E)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant python code.

Comment: Provided the full python code.